# "Цель, которУЮ (или которОЙ) надо достичь"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Цель, которУЮ (или которОЙ) надо достичь"?

Answer (score 4):

1. Первое слово в предложении - ЦЕЛЬ - существительное. Определение к нему выражено сложноподчиненным предложением, которое и отвечает на вопрос КАКУЮ".
   Придаточное предложение согласуется со словом "цель", отвечая на вопрос "КАКУЮ?".
   Следовательно, нужно писать: 
   Цель, кото**рую** надо достичь.
2. Если в начале предложение идет глагол - Достичь. От него вопрос -  *ЧЕГО?* (достичь - *чего?*). 
   В этом случае верно согласование существительного с глаголом за счет употребления существительного в Род. п.: 
   достичь целИ (чего? р.п.)

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку достичь можно цель и цели, то и которую/которой допустимо. 
Эти варианты несколько отличаются в смысловом отношении - они передают, насколько конкретна или случайна упоминаемая цель.
Без контекста трудно сказать, какой вариант точнее передает ситуацию, но в нейтральном оформлении я бы предпочел ***"Цель, которую надо достичь"***. Сравните: *"рубеж, который надо достичь"* vs *"Рубеж, которого надо достичь"*. Первое, т.е. винительный падеж, явно предпочтительнее на слух.

Answer (score 0):

Цель, которой надо достичь. Здесь глагол достичь управляет Р.п. местоимения в роли союзного слова.
ОТВЕТ 2.
"Глагол "достичь" допускает при себе и родительный, и винительный падеж. Не уверен даже, что первое предпочтительнее, скорее наоборот".
Откуда такие сведения? Все словари уверяют: достичь (чего?). У Розенталя в справочнике "Управление в русском языке" дается: достичь (чего?) и достичь до (чего?) как устаревшее. О В.п. нет ни слова.

ОТВЕТ 3.

Выражение «Цель, которой надо достичь, - это не предложение, а только его часть.  Составим предложение, например: Надо руководствоваться ЦЕЛЬЮ (Т.п.), КОТОРОЙ (Д.п.) надо достичь. Это СПП с придаточным определительным, слово «которой» является союзным словом. Как можно видеть, определяемое существительное «целью» и союзное слово «которой» стоят в разных падежах. Слово «который» заменяет существительное «цель» в придаточным предложении, но УПРАВЛЯЕТ им глагол "достичь". СОГЛАСОВАНИЯ в падеже в таких предложениях нет.

Может быть только СОВПАДЕНИЕ падежей, например: Нет цели (Р.П.), которой (Р.п.) надо достичь. Или (если вы выбрали В.п. для глагола "достичь" в придаточном предложении): Я вижу цель (В.п.), которую (В.п.)надо достичь.

Comment: Глагол "достичь" допускает при себе и родительный, и винительный падеж. Первое предпочтительнее, но не императивно.

Comment: достичь кого? что? -  не достичь кого? чего?

Comment: >достичь кого? что? - не достичь кого? чего?

Нет. Родительный при отрицании - это отдельная песня. 
И без "не" нормативно ***Достичь кого/чего*** и ***достичь кого/что***. Причем первое - вернее.  
  
"Курс доллара достиг психологически значимой величины". Не "величину" же. "Мы достигли вершины горы". "Функция достигает своего максимума" - и проч.